# php pdo code to get max value inside for loop and insert row

Tags: php, pdo

column - book_no

I created forloop to loop insert query according to user inputed values ok.

But if the DB has max value 5 in book_no column then next time values insert in book_no column starts from 6.

Ex: suppose my book_no column has already 1,2,3,4,5 values present in DB, now I Enter 3 in book_no textbox from UI FORM.
Then my code insert again 3 new rows and values goes in book_no column is 6,7,8.

plz suggest how to get max value and from DB and get this inside loop.

```
 $book_no = $_POST['book_no'];                  
 $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $sub_inner = $database->getRows("SELECT MAX(book_no) FROM scheme_master where book_no = :book_no",
 array(':book_no'=>$book_no)); 
 $max =     $exists['maxbook_no'] + 1;
 for($row=1;$row<=$book_no;$row++)
 {  
     $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,created) VALUES (:book_no,:created)", 
     array(':book_no'=>$max,':created'=>$created));
 }
```

Comment: edit your question to be more clear and include a screenshot of your table.

Comment: actually  my que. is.. when user enter 4 then it insert 4 rows in database and values goes in book_no column like 1,2,3,4 ok..again when i enter 3 then loop will run 3 times and values goes inside book_no column from 5,6,7 not again from 1,2,3. plz help ..thanks in advance...

Comment: i just created my accound on stack and i have no reputation to post image.

Comment: i have upvoted your que. try uploading an image.

Comment: i tried to upload image...but fail due to minimum 10 reputations.

Comment: book_no 1,2,3,4,...1,2,3 like this values goes inside my table..

Comment: every time vale starts from 1,2,3, and so on...

Comment: what you are saying is if the user enters 4 then 1 up to 4 need to be inserted in the column book_no, taking 4 rows.?

Comment: yes .......exactly and again when user enter 3 then 5 upto 7 to be inserted in the column book_no and so on........

Answer (score 0):

try this code if it works, edit it to bind your values

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.serversfree.com; dbname=u615496488_data','u615496488_data','24222222');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$number = $_POST['text'];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number ; $i++) { 
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM book_no');
    $max = $results->rowCount() + 1; //get the max number by getting row count
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO `book_no`(`Book_No`) VALUES ($max)");
}
}
?>
```

[see demo here](http://testpdo.bugs3.com/)